# Spring Boot Oauth2 mapping google users to mine

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, google-oauth

I'm just wrapping my head on Oauth2. I have a Spring boot app with its own users and roles system handled by Spring Security 5. Internally I use email to identify users, I want people who registered with their gmail addresses to be able to log in through Oauth2. Or, more generally, how do I make one of my users log in to my app using Oauth2? If you need code or more information just ask. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you are looking for a general approach to authenticate users for using your Spring Boot application with the help of OAuth2 protocol.

In your case you will probably use Google as an authentication provider and your application as resource server, according to the OAuth2 standard wording. First at all to answer your general question, there are different ways of using OAuth2 to authenticate users. A good starting points are these links:

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749
- https://auth0.com

To find the proper way of implementing OAuth2 for your usecase I recommend using this decision tree: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use

For starting to implement OAuth2 in Spring Boot you can use several Spring Security projects with further documentation:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-oauth2
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/